# Stuck in Linux after booting from USB

Tags: linux, windows, drivers, keyboard, multi-boot

Ok so I just bought a Surface Laptop (first gen). As a programmer, it is important for me to dual boot linux (Manjaro). I had done this by the past so it should not have been too much of a problem. However there were many security features enabled that blocked the installation of a second os. After a few minutes of trying to bypass them, I've been able to boot from my USB stick. Unfortunately the keyboard driver was not working so I had to update it. While I was playing around the screen became black , showing only the mouse. Now I can't exit the live USB. The Power off button is located on the keyboard and since the keyboard driver does not work, I can't turn the laptop off and boot into Windows. Please help me!

TLDR : I booted into a Linux USB Stick, the keyboard driver does not work, the only power off button is on the keyboard so I can't exit and boot back into Windows. Even the GUI is not showing, only the mouse on a black background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following sequence is not driver dependent (copied from microsoft support page):

```
1) Press and hold the power button on your Surface for 30 seconds and then release it.
2) Press and hold the volume-up button and the power button at the same time for at least 15 seconds and then release both.
The screen may flash the Surface logo, but continue holding the buttons down for at least 15 seconds.
```

For future debugging: It may be due to videocard driver issues, wich may cause a complete hang of your OS (therefore black screen, no keyboard response). It may help to add 'nomodeset' as a boot parameter, once you've come to the point of rebooting your laptop.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You are my literal savior. God bless you.

Comment: Glad it helped you!